# Passing Array as prop not received on the other component

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I am trying to pass an array of objects as a prop to a component. The Array is being passed without an array. I am neither receiving any compilation error.

I tried actually looking on to the object tried some stuff. But it did not work

Here is the code:

CardRenderer.vue:

```
<template lang="html">

  <div>       
    <b-container class="bv-example-row">      
       <b-row v-for="(row, i) of rows" v-bind:key="i">       
          <b-col v-for="(item, j) of row" v-bind:key="j" >
                    <!-- you card -->
              <b-card 
                :title="item.title" 
                img-src="item.icon" 
                img-alt="Image" 
                img-top 
                tag="article" 
                style="max-width: 20rem;" 
                class="mb-2"
              >
                <b-card-text>
                  <h1>{{item.name}}</h1>
                  <pre>{{item.description}}</pre>
                </b-card-text>
                  <b-button :href="'/dashboard/'+item.name" variant="primary">More</b-button>
              </b-card>                
          </b-col>
        </b-row>
    </b-container>    
  </div>

</template>

<script lang="js">
  export default  {
    name: 'CardRenderer',
    props: {
      renderData: {
        type: Array,
        required: true,
        default: () => ([]),
      }      
    },
     data() {
      return {
        rows: null
      }
    },
    mounted() {

      const itemsPerRow = 3
      let rowss = []
      // eslint-disable-next-line
      console.log(this.renderData)
      let arr = this.renderData

      for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i += itemsPerRow) {
          let row = []
          for (let z = 0; z < itemsPerRow; z++) {
            row.push(arr[z])
          }
          rowss.push(row)
      }


      this.rows = rowss

      // eslint-disable-next-line                
      // console.log(this.rows) 

    },

    methods: {

    },
    computed: {
      //  rows() {
      //  }

    }
  }
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

Something.vue

```
<template lang="html">
    <!-- <h1>Something</h1> -->
    <CardRenderer :renderData=valObj />
</template>

<script lang="js">
import CardRenderer from './CardRenderer'

    export default  {
        name: 'something',
        components: {
            CardRenderer
        },
        props: [],

        data() {
            return {
                valObj: []
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            let key = this.findUrl()
            let value = this.$store.getters.responseAPI.apps.filter((elem) => {
                if(elem.name == key) return elem.apps
            })

            if (value && value.length > 0)
                this.valObj = value[0].apps
            //eslint-disable-next-line
            console.log(this.valObj)
        },
        methods: {
            findUrl() {
                let url  = window.location.pathname.split("/").slice(-1)[0];
                return url
            }       
        },
        computed: {

        }
    }
</script>

<style scoped >
  .something {

  }
</style>
```

This is what i am sending as a prop.

[image]

This is what i receive on the component

[image]

Comment: Try `<CardRenderer :render-data="valObj" />` in your `Something` template

Comment: it Did not work

Comment: Please [update your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56592345/edit) to show what you changed

Comment: I did not even find relatable apart from the kabab-case. My issue is specific to the sending & receiving of the props. I am  receiving just the observer part not the array. While the post you mentioned above somewhere relates to overriding

Comment: Read the linked answer... _"when you’re using in-DOM templates, camelCased prop names need to use their kebab-cased (hyphen-delimited) equivalents"_. You are using `renderData` as an attribute where you should be using `render-data`.

Comment: I did.. even tried it. it did not work either

Comment: Also, `mounted` hooks only run **once**. Since you're updating the `valObj` in the parent component `mounted` hook, it won't magically re-run the child component `mounted` hook

Comment: May be a solution for that would work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of issues here.

First, you should be using kebab-cased attribute names and quotes around the value...

```html
<CardRenderer :render-data="valObj" />
```

The second issue is timing related. In your component, you calculate `rows` based on the initial `renderData` in the `mounted` hook but this will not update when the parent component alters `valObj`.

What you should do instead is use a computed property which will react to `valObj` / `renderData` changes.

For example

```js
data () { return {} }, // removed rows from data
computed: {
  rows () {
    let itemsPerRow = 3
    let rows = []
    for (let i = 0; i < this.renderData.length; i += itemsPerRow) {
      rows.push(this.renderData.slice(i, i + itemsPerRow))
    }
    return rows
  }
}
```